# Android : com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth#getInstance has been removed by Proguard

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, sdk, android-proguard

Sometime I get this error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth#getInstance has been removed by Proguard. Add keep rule to prevent it.**

*If I clean and rebuild then it will start working fine, but the question is still alive why this is happening even if the proguard is disable?*

I am using below version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

And it is happening while making a debug build, and in debug build proguard is disable. so I am wondering why it's trowing error related to proguard.

Comment: have you tried by adding `-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }` in proguard config ?

Comment: in debug build proguard is disable

Comment: as per your suggestion I added and still same error.

Comment: might be another issue

Comment: I clean and rebuild then it's working, but the question is still alive why it's throwing this error?

Comment: now Is it work always ?

Comment: Actually yesterday I was facing this issue and I did clean and rebuild after that same it was working fine, but today again I have seen this issue. 
that the reason I have mentioned in question itself 'sometime'.
Now it's working...